# Context.SaveChanges() is not working

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entities, savechanges

The following is my code. When I see table data after executing of this code, it still is blank. Any ideas to make the following code work would be appreciated.

Dim dbcontext As New Model1Container

```
    Dim employee As New emp
    employee.empid = 1
    employee.empname = "some name"
    employee.empaddress = "some address"
    dbcontext.emps.AddObject(employee)

    Try
        dbcontext.SaveChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I am using VS 2010 Professional Edition and SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: are you getting any error or exceptions?

Comment: nope. no errors no exceptions. everything is working fine. but the data is not getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

Didyou try with `dbcontext.SubmitChanges()`

[Reference - 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx)

[Reference - 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2010/12/17/select-insert-update-and-delete-data-with-linq-to-sql-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx)

Comment: I am using linq to entities there is no submitchanges option in my data context.

Comment: I switched to linq to sql just to check if I can insert data in to the system, but no luck.

Comment: here is linq to sql code i used.

        Dim db As New AppDataContext

        Dim employee As New emp
        employee.empname = "some name"
        employee.empaddress = "some address"
        db.emps.InsertOnSubmit(employee)
        db.SubmitChanges()

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a local database file? You may be looking for changes in the wrong place. By default, when the program starts, VS copies the database file into the debug or release folder. Then the program runs and changes are made, and saved, to the file in the debug or release folder. The program ends, and when you look at the database in your source folder it looks the same. You can change the connection string in the app.config to use an absolute path to avoid this.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx for more info